# how can we take value of an id in to a variable in modal

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, bootstrap-modal

Here i want to take the value of an `id` in to a variable in order to get the result based on the value of the `id`,for example my id value contains the value `19849` and i want that result to be passed to a variable.
here is my code

```
<input type="text"  name="bill_no" class="form-control" id="bill_no">
 <?php $a_results=$this->db->get_where('datas',array('bill_no'=>19849))->row();?>
```

from above code in my modal i have the value `19849` in my input text and now i want to pass that value in place of `19849` where i used directly.

Comment: take value by js $('#bill_no').val() , then stores to variable

Comment: Firstly, if you are using the CI framework you should never include db queries in a view. Check out the MVC principle https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

Comment: by doing that only i got value in my input text and now i want to take that value and paste in my php query

Comment: Sure, You cannot run server side queries on client, so only way without reloading the page is using ajax.

Answer (score 3):

You need to send Ajax request to the controller. Using Ajax pass the bill_no(19849) to the controller. From controller query the DB using model and use the $_POST['bill_no'] to fetch the result from the DB for that bill_no.

Return this result using json_encode from controller and read the data in jQuery using $.parseJSON

That's how MVC works.You need to follow the MVC structure.

Hope you get the clear idea how it works?

Comment: This is right. However use CI default way of getting input data to secure your code. `$this->input->post('bill_no')` instead of `$_POST`